# Publish web on Azure. Operation could destabilize the runtime in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I published my web project to Azure and when I pull it up in the browser I see the error below.
I fixed the same error by disabling IntelliTrace, when I published my Web ROLE to windows azure. But I could not find where to disable it in Publish web settings.
http://www.windowsazure.com/media/devcenter/dotnet/dev-net-getting-started-039.png

[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1..ctor() in c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\AbstractValidator.cs:36
   Poll.Areas.Shared.Validators.Account.LogOnValidator..ctor() in D:\Code\Poll\Poll\Areas\Shared\Validators\Account\LogOnValidator.cs:15

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
   FluentValidation.Internal.InstanceCache.GetOrCreateInstance(Type type, Func`2 factory) in c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Internal\InstanceCache.cs:58
   FluentValidation.Internal.InstanceCache.GetOrCreateInstance(Type type) in c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Internal\InstanceCache.cs:37
   FluentValidation.Attributes.AttributedValidatorFactory.GetValidator(Type type) in c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\Attributes\AttributedValidatorFactory.cs:48
   FluentValidation.Mvc.FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) in c:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation.Mvc3\FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.cs:75
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetValidators>b__6(ModelValidatorProvider provider) +21
       System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext() +234
   System.Linq.d__14`2.MoveNext() +397
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(String name, ModelMetadata metadata) +297
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, String name, Object value, Boolean useViewData, Boolean isChecked, Boolean setId, Boolean isExplicitValue, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +794
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.HiddenHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value, Boolean useViewData, String expression, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +124
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.HiddenFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +90
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.HiddenFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression) +54

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this problem by "Enable package manager restore". Right click on solution -> Enable package manager restore

Answer (score 1):

If you think it's IntelliTrace, and you've enabled it, you can disable it by:

- Right click on your Cloud Project
- Select Publish
- Go to Settings
- Advanced
- (Un)check the "IntelliTrace" checkbox

[image: IntelliTrace Disable]

This dialog is only available when you chose the "Publish" action for the context menu.

Comment: When I done it to my web role, it worked. But i have the same problem in my web app. And when i publish it, there is no such property. http://www.windowsazure.com/media/devcenter/dotnet/dev-net-getting-started-039.png
so maybe it is not problem with IntelliTrace.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to use IntelliTrace by taking a look at the top of your exception stack and add exception module in advanced settings. Explained [here](http://ingeniarius.net/blog/azure-web-role-intelli-trace-castle-windsor-something-operation-destabilize-runtime-verificationexception/).